# how to copy description user in batch file

Tags: batch

**Copy description user in batch file**

How can I copy the description of a user in a batch file?
And copy to clipboard and paste in a text file

Comment: Your own user's description?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get your own user description into a text file let's say description.txt:

```
wmic useraccount where name="%username%" get description>>description.txt
```

To get some other users description:

```
wmic useraccount where name="SomeUsername" get description>>description.txt
```

To save it to clipboard:

```
wmic useraccount where name="%username%" get description |clip
```

If there was no description defined for that user, you won't get any description from that command of course...

Comment: Very Thanks My Friend